# How big is the set of hypersurfaces with bad singularities?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_d$ be the set of all homogeneous polynomials with degree $d$, and let 
$$S_i =\{f \in R \mid \text{first $i$-th order derivatives of $f$ are all zero at $x$, for some $x\in Z(f)$}\}.$$

I would like to know that, what is the codimension of $S_i$ in $R$? For example, $S_1$ consists of such $Z(f)$ is singular, and it is well-known that $\mathrm{codim}(S_1)=1$. But I don’t know how to do for a general $i$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach this kind of question is by using a sort of incidence correspondence to linearise the problem. I don't have time to write all details, but I can sketch the idea in case it helps you.

Let me change notation slightly so that $R$ is the polynomial ring in $n+1$ variables. So the polynomials you are asking about define hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbf P^n$. The space of such hypersurfaces is $\mathbf P^N$ where $N={n+d \choose d}-1$.

Now define
$$\Sigma_i = \left\{ (x,V) \in \mathbf P^n \times \mathbf P^N \mid V \text{ has a singularity of multiplicity of order $ \geq i$ at } x \right\}.$$

Then $S_i$ is the projection of $\Sigma_i$ onto the $\mathbf P^N$ factor. (Actually your definition of $S_i$ differs from this by scalar multiplication, but that doesn't affect the codimension, so let's not worry.)

Why is this helpful? The point is that we can understand $\Sigma_i$ by looking at its projection onto the $\mathbf P^n$ factor. For a fixed $x \in \mathbf P^n$, the set of hypersurfaces with a singularity of order $\geq i$ at $x$ is a *linear subspace* of $\mathbf P^N$ whose codimension is easy to calculate (just count the number of partial derivatives which are vanishing). Since $\mathbf P^n$ is homogeneous, the answer is the same for all $x$. So $\Sigma_i$ is a $\mathbf P^m$-bundle over $\mathbf P^n$, for some value of $m$ that you have just calculated.

Then the last step is to project to $\mathbf P^N$. I claim that this projection is finite, so the dimension of $S_i$ actually the same as that of $\Sigma_i$. To prove the claim, it suffices to find a single hypersurface of degree $d$ with a nonempty finite set of points of multiplicity $i$. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! There is a small typo: the $N$ should be $N-1$. And, in the computation of $m$, one needs to know that there is how many linear dependences in the partial derivatives. For example, there is one dependence in the first order, i.e. the Euler identity. Similarly one can show there is at least one more once we add the order. I would like to know that, is there more linear dependence besides this?

Comment: To determine multiplicity at a given point $x$ you can switch to affine coordinates around $x$ and compute partial derivatives in those coordinates. Then they are independent, but there is one variable fewer, hence fewer partial derivatives, corresponding to the relations you mention.

Comment: I changed the definition of $N$ rather than changing every $N$ to $N-1$.

Comment: Yes you are right, using the affine coordinations one is easy to see the independence. Thanks a lot.